# Charging Paint either negatively or positively to repel paint with the same charge

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Is it possible to give paint a negative or positive charge.  Once dry, if you tried to paint on the surface with the same charged paint, would it just run down and refuse to stick?

Comment: In general, it is not possible to give _anything_ a charge.

Comment: But what about this:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_coating

Comment: I am curious about the possibility for Anti-Graffiti purposes.  If it's possible to charge the paint a municipality uses to cover graffiti so that it repels spray paint in the same manner that two negative poles of a magnet repel each other.